# Existence of a unique state-representation relation in C*-algebras

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

My question is whether there exists a unique cyclic and separating state on a C$\ast$-algebra giving rise to a specific representation (in other words is it possible to reverse the GNS construction)? If there is, then how can we find it ? If not, are there any specific extra constraints that we should impose on the state to be unique?

Since there is a bijection correspondence between non-degenerate representation $\pi$ of a $\ast$-algebra $\mathbb{C}\mathcal{G}$ and unitary representation $U$ of $\mathcal{G}$, I'm ultimately interested in finding a unique cyclic and separating state,$\omega_U$, over $\mathbb{C}\mathcal{G}$ given the unitary representation $U$ of $\mathcal{G}$. To be more specific I want to start with a unitary representation of a Lie group (SU(N) for instance) and find the corresponding cyclic and separating state to that representation on the group C$\ast$-algebra.

Comment: I'm a physicist and I'm new to this field so my apologies if this question is basic or doesn't make any sense at all...

Comment: If $\mathcal A$ is a $C^*$ algebra with a representation $\pi$ that has a cyclic state $\Omega$, then any Element of $\mathcal A^\times\Omega$ is also a cyclic vector (here $\mathcal A^\times$ are the invertible elements of $\mathcal A$).

So uniqueness of a cyclic vector is pretty much impossible, but there might exist canonical constructions of cyclic vectors given a cyclic $*$ representation.